# Django restframework test permissions

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework, django-testing

Which is the proper way to test object based permissions?

Sample:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOfficeAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        office = obj
        return office.admin == request.user
```

- Which are the "asserts" that I shouldn't miss?
- Do I need to create a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your questions:

- it's up to you to write the logic which will allow a user to access the object. As a result, you have to return a Boolean.
- yes. You will specify to the view which permission classes you want to apply. In case of object permissions they will be queried on detail routes (get, update, delete)